# What's the intended use of IllegalStateException?

Tags: java, exception, illegalstateexception

This came up in a discussion with a colleague today.

The Javadocs for Java's [`IllegalStateException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalStateException.html) state that it:

> Signals that a method has been invoked at an illegal or inappropriate time. In other words, the Java environment or Java application is not in an appropriate state for the requested operation.

And Effective Java says (Item 60, page 248):

> Another commonly reused exception is IllegalStateException. This is generally the exception to throw if the invocation is illegal because of the state of the receiving object. For example, this would be the exception to throw if the caller attempted to use some object before it had been properly initialized.

It seems there's a bit of discrepancy here. The second sentence of the javadocs makes it sound like the exception could describe a very broad condition about the Java execution state, but the description in Effective Java makes it sound like it's used for conditions related specifically to the state of the object whose method has been called.

The usages I've seen in the JDK (e.g. collections, `Matcher`) and in Guava definitely seem to fall into the category that Effective Java talks about ("This object is in a state where this method can't be called"). This also seems consistent with `IllegalStateException`'s sibling `IllegalArgumentException`.

Are there any legitimate `IllegalStateException` usages in the JDK that do relate to the "Java environment" or "Java application"? Or do any best practices guides advocate using it for the broader execution state? If not, why the heck are the javadocs phrased like that? ;)

Comment: On an maybe unrelated, note, I noticed StackOverflow's [illegalstatexception] tag says `In Java, an exception that occurs when using multiple threads, whereby one thread modifies an object in a way that makes it incompatible with the use of that object in the second thread, thus putting the object into an illegal state.`. Huh? Where does this come from?

Comment: The "Java application" is the one you write, and you can use `IllegalStateException` there (either directly or because you're using Guava, for example). Where's the discrepancy?

Comment: The tag wiki looks bogus, I have submitted an edit by liberally borrowing from this question; you should see the new version once it has passed peer review.

Answer (score 47):

Here is one particularly legitimate usage of this exception in JDK (see: [`URLConnection.setIfModifiedSince(long)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/net/URLConnection.java#URLConnection.setIfModifiedSince(long)) among 300+ other usages of it:

```
public void setIfModifiedSince(long ifmodifiedsince) {
    if (connected)
        throw new IllegalStateException("Already connected");
    ifModifiedSince = ifmodifiedsince;
}
```

I think the example is pretty clear. If the object is in particular state ("*Already connected*"), some operations should not be called. In this case when connection was established, some properties cannot be set.

This exception is especially useful when your class has some state (state machine?) that changes over time, making some methods irrelevant or impossible. Think about a `Car` class that has `start()`, `stop()` and `fuel()` methods. While calling `start()` twice, one after another, is probably nothing wrong, but fueling a started car is certainly a bad idea. Namely - car is in a wrong state.

Arguably good API should not allow us to call methods in wrong state so that problems like that are discovered at compile time, not at runtime. In this particular example connecting to a URL should return a different object with a subset of methods, all of which are valid after connecting.

Comment: I agree with your answer. But this doesn't explain why Effectiva Java and Guava uses this Exception like an ``IllegalArgumentException``

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example in the JDK.  There is a package private class called java.lang.Shutdown. If the system is shutting down and you attempt to add a new hook, it throws the IllegalStateException.  One could argue that this meets the criteria of the "javadoc" guidance - since it is the Java environment that is in the wrong state.

```
class Shutdown {    
...

   /* Add a new shutdown hook.  Checks the shutdown state and the hook itself,
    * but does not do any security checks.
    */
    static void add(int slot, Runnable hook) {
        synchronized (lock) {
            if (state > RUNNING)
                throw new IllegalStateException("Shutdown in progress");

            if (hooks[slot] != null)
                throw new InternalError("Shutdown hook at slot " + slot + " already registered");

            hooks[slot] = hook;
        }
    }
```

However it also illustrates that there really is no distinction between the "javadoc" guidance and the "Effective Java" guidance.  Because of the way Shutdown is implemented, the shutdown-ness of the JVM is stored in a field called state.  Therefore it also meets the "Effective Java" guidance for when to use IllegalStateException, since the "state" field is part of the state of the receiving object. Since the receiving object (Shutdown) is in the wrong state, it throws the IllegalStateException.

In my opinion the two descriptions of when to use IllegalStateException are consistent.  The Effective Java description is a bit more practical, that's all.  For most of us, the most important part of the entire Java environment is the class that we are writing right now, so that is what the author is focusing on.

Comment: Ah, I like this example! The `InternalError` throw just below the ISE also demonstrates how useful it is to make a "You messed up" vs "I messed up" distinction. Also, it does show how static state (you could say "Java Application" or "Java Environment" state) still counts as state as far as ISEs are concerned.

Comment: @AndrewMcNamee I think that `AssertionError` would be more appropriate for cases where I know that I messed up. It seems be an `InternalError` only because it's inside JDK code rather than application code - a dubious distinction.

Comment: Yep, I definitely agree about `AssertionError`; it seems to convey "I messed up" as opposed to "You messed up" (which ISE implies). I use it a lot in the `default` case for `switch`es. IMO `InternalError` still serves a useful purpose; the person reading stack trace knows they can assume "Whoa, the JDK messed up", but the JDK authors probably could have left it out.

Answer (score 2):

I guess if you see usage of `IllegalStateException` I would say second if more appropriate. This exception is used in lot of packages

- java.net
- java.nio
- java.util
- java.util.concurrrent etc

To specify one example [ArrayBlockingQueue.add](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html#add%28E%29) throws this exception if queue is already full. Now full is state of the object and it is being invoked at inappropriate or Illegal time

I guess both means same but difference of wording.

Answer (score 1):

Given a library, it should throw an `IllegalStateException` or `IllegalArgumentException` whenever it detects a bug due to the user code, whereas the library should throw an `AssertionError` whenever it detects a bug due to the library's own implementation.

For example, in the library's tests, you may expect the library throws an `IllegalStateException` when the order of method calls are wrong. But you will never expect the library throws an `AssertionError`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no 'discrepancy' here. There is nothing in Bloch's wording that excludes what it says in the JLS. Bloch is simply saying that if you have circumstance A, throw this exception. He is *not* saying that this exception is/should be thrown *only* in this condition. The JLS is saying this exception is thrown if A, B, or C.

Comment: I suppose you could say that. But on the other hand, if it did have intended usage circumstances that were different from the circumstance he gave, then the might not be as meaningful since it'd be less specific. In other words, if ISE were intended to be used in other circumstances than the current "You called this method on me, but I'm not in a state where I can do that" case, it might not be as informative. But admittedly, I think I'm splitting hairs here ;)

Comment: @AndrewMcNamee I *did* say that. I don't know what the rest of your comment even means, but you are trying to manufacture a discrepancy where none exists. You are committing a logical fallacy.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this with:

```
try {
    MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
    ...
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    throw new AssertionError(e);
}
```

I think it will be impractical for me to throw `IllegalStateException` here in place of `AssertionException` even though this falls into the "the Java environment" category.