# IllegalStateException in the context of multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, illegalstateexception

I am learning core java and learned about multithreading `IllegalStateException`.

I have already read [standard documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalStateException.html) and [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12698275/whats-the-intended-use-of-illegalstateexception)...but couldn't find proper solution in the context of threads.

In book's words:

> `IllegalStateException` is thrown when you start a thread twice.

I can not understand what it says..even no example is given..

When it occurs in the context of threads? Can anyone give an example?

Comment: Yes, it means calling `Thread.start()` twice.

Comment: @markspace can you give an example when actually IllegalStateException occurs in multithreading?

Comment: What do you think _when you start a thread twice_ means? Do you know how to start a thread?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis ok..now understood..I'm fool.:)..may be my knowledge is vague.

Comment: Yes, this is not complicated.  Sometimes you think things are difficult, when they're not.  Just a little thought is required to work it out.

Comment: Just ask yourself those questions.

Comment: @markspace a little thought is worthless unless it doesn't spark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Thread t = new Thread();
      t.start();
      t.start();
   }
```

Produces:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException    at
java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:682)     at
quicktest.CopyOnWrite.main(CopyOnWrite.java:23)
Java Result: 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can't call the start method of the Thread if it's already started.

> public void start()
>
> Causes this thread to begin execution; the Java Virtual Machine calls
>   the run method of this thread.
>
> The result is that two threads are running concurrently: the current
>   thread (which returns from the call to the start method) and the other
>   thread (which executes its run method).
>
> **It is never legal to start a thread more than once. In particular, a
>   thread may not be restarted once it has completed execution.**
>
> Throws:
>       **IllegalThreadStateException - if the thread was already started.**
>
> See Also:
>      run(), stop()

([Source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start--))