# Getting java.lang.IllegalStateException: for child view

Tags: java, android, android-layout, illegalstateexception, removechild

I am inflating a layout dynamically. I want to add child views in that layout. I tried to add this but getting exception:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first

Event function:

```
  private void createEvent(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup dayplanView, int fromMinutes, int toMinutes, String title,String location) {
    final View eventView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.event_view, dayplanView, false);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) eventView.getLayoutParams();

    RelativeLayout container = (RelativeLayout) eventView.findViewById(R.id.container);
    TextView tvTitle = (TextView) eventView.findViewById(R.id.textViewTitle);

    TextView showLocation = (TextView)eventView.findViewById(R.id.At);

    if (tvTitle.getParent() != null)
        ((ViewGroup) tvTitle.getParent()).removeView(tvTitle);
    tvTitle.setText(title);
    if (showLocation.getParent() != null)
        ((ViewGroup) showLocation.getParent()).removeView(showLocation);
    showLocation.setText(location);

    if(location == null)
    {
        showLocation.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    else {
      showLocation.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }

    int distance = (toMinutes - fromMinutes);

    layoutParams.topMargin = dpToPixels(fromMinutes + 9);
    layoutParams.height = dpToPixels(distance);

    eventView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    dayplanView.addView(eventView);
    dayplanView.addView(showLocation);
    container.addView(tvTitle);
    container.addView(showLocation);


    eventView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            i = new Intent(getActivity(),AddEventActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });

}
```

event view layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/shape"
        android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp">

        <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:id="@+id/textViewTitle"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_marginTop="01dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:id="@+id/At"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textViewTitle"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textViewTitle"
            android:layout_marginTop="01dp"
            android:text="At : "
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Getting exception on   container.addView(showLocation);

Same exception I had for title so I did this:

```
if (tvTitle.getParent() != null)
        ((ViewGroup) tvTitle.getParent()).removeView(tvTitle);
```

So the problem was solved. But now I want to ad another text view in the view. Its giving same error again I tried to remove this view same way.

if (showLocation.getParent() != null)
            ((ViewGroup) showLocation.getParent()).removeView(showLocation);

Still getting exception.

Whats wrong.?

Comment: Can you post stack trace?

Comment: solved it.. thank you.. @Msp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally IllegalStateException thorws when a method is invoked in an object which are not in proper state(Illegal State), For instance an object which is not properly initialized or stall state

Please have also a look in SOF [What's the intended use of IllegalStateException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12698275/whats-the-intended-use-of-illegalstateexception) and https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/246250/illegalstateexception-vs-illegalargumentexception