# What exception to throw if an operation would bring the object into an illegal state?

Tags: java, exception, illegalstateexception, runtimeexception

Consider a `Product` with a `quantity` which can be increased and decreased by a given `amount`. The quantity should never become negative and if it is going to happen, the operation must be prohibited and the user warned.

```
public class Product{
    
    private int quantity;
    
    public Product() {
        quantity = 10;
    }
    
    public void decreaseQuantity(int amount) {
        int decreasedQuantity = quantity - amount;
        if(decreasedQuantity < 0 )
            throw new RuntimeException(String.format("Decrease quantity (%s) exceeds avaiable quantity (%s)",
                    amount, quantity));
        
        quantity = decreasedQuantity;
    }
}
```

For example if a product has quantity 10 and I try to remove 20, I throw a RuntimeException. SonarCloud suggests to replace the RuntimeException with a Custom exception, but I was wondering if there is a standard exception suitable for this case (*Effective Java: Favor The Use of Standard Exceptions*).

The most suitable exception seems to be `IllegalStateException`. From the javadoc

> Signals that a method has been invoked at an illegal or inappropriate time. In other words, the Java environment or Java application is not in an appropriate state for the requested operation.

and from Effective Java

> IllegalStateException: This exception is used if, when a method is called, the state of the object is not valid for that operation. Potentially you have a filehandle and you call read before it has been opened.

However, it seems to me that there is a subtle difference between my example and what is assumed in the docs: it is not the state of the object **itself** that makes the operation illegal, it's the state of the object **and** the value of the input parameter. Reading usage examples (like [What's the intended use of IllegalStateException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12698275/whats-the-intended-use-of-illegalstateexception)) the object is always in a state where the operation is rejected regardless of the input parameter.

Comment: There is no immovable rule about the kind of exception to throw in java. It depends totaly on the way you would handle it. You could also create a custom exception inherited from `java.lang.Exception` or its subclasses

Comment: I would say `IllegalArgumentException` - as in the argument `20` is illegal. But `IllegalStateException` makes sense too. Personally though I would write a custom exception that’s descriptive - there is very little cost to adding classes.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Honestly, I discarded `IllegalArgumentException` because i think it would be ok if the argument were illegal regardless of the state. For example, if the given amount is negative I throw an `IllegalArgumentException` because a negative amount will never be right. On the other hand, the parameter `20` is not always illegal, it is illegal just in the current situation. I would need a mixture of IllegalStateException and IllegalArgumentException. I'll look for IAE usage similar to my example and update you. I may have discarded it too early, you may be right.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I found an example in effective java that seems equivalent to the one in my question. Following what the book says, the correct answer is IllegalArgumentException.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing in the core java libraries that is a slam dunk. However, make your own exception is probably your best bet, it's a close race between that and using `IllegalArgumentException`.

### `RuntimeException`

Ill advised for nebulous reasons. The primary reason not to use it, is because linter tools will yell at you. The reason they yell at you is twofold, and to determine whether the right move is to tell the linters to shut up, or to head their advice, is to focus on these 2 reasons:

1. The type name of the exception is itself information. For example, `throw new NullPointerException("x is null")` is dumb code to write (even though its common). It's superfluous - just `new NullPointerException("x")` is appropriate. `RuntimeException` conveys almost no information at all. You are mostly avoiding this trap: Whilst RuntimeException indeed conveys nearly nothing, the message of the exception says it all, therefore, the thing the linter is trying to stop from happening (throwing an exception that doesn't properly convey the nature of the problem) isn't happening, and thus you should consider just telling the linter to stop whining... except for:
2. The second reason you want a proper exception type is that you really, really don't want code that intends to catch this to have to do string analysis on an exception message. Thus, if there's any world in which you can foresee that some code wants to invoke your method and then react to the condition (of trying to subtract more than available) in any way other than blowing up all context, then you should be throwing an exception that means this specific condition and nothing else. `RuntimeException` is **never** appropriate to catch if your intent is to catch a specific condition (it's pretty much never appropriate, period - sometimes you want to run code and react to any problem regardless of its nature, but then `catch (Exception e)` is the appropriate catch block, or even `Throwable`. e.g. appservers and the like should be doing this.

### `IllegalArgumentException`

The linters won't be yelling, but you're still not really getting the secondary benefit (that is, allow callers to catch this specific problem and not some other problem with the arguments). It's also 'mentally' slightly dubious: Your reasons for initially disregarding it are not wrong. Generally IAEs are understood to imply that the illegal argument is illegal regardless of the state of this object. But this isn't written in IAE's javadoc and isn't universally applied.

So, downsides are:

- It's a bit of a push to force callers to `catch (IllegalArgumentException e)` to deal with wanting to react to subtracting more than is there. IAE is still too 'general'.
- It could be lightly confusing.

Upside is simply:

- It's already there.

### `IllegalStateException`

I think this is strictly worse than IAE. It's mostly the same story, except here the confusion is that ISE is usually used to flag that the current state of the object is such that the operation you are trying to call is simply not available. In a tweaked way that's actually true (the object's state is that there are 3 items; therefore it is not in a state that `decreaseQuantity(5)` is an available operation right now), but it feels more confusing than IAE: ISE feels like the Product object itself is in an invalid state. I'd be assuming that the product is a legacy product that is not now or will ever be in stock again, or is some dummy product type (a Product object representing 'unknown product' or something similarly exotic).

But, same deal with IAE: The javadoc of ISE doesn't specifically spell out that you couldn't do it. Hence, if you would prefer to throw this, you could, it's not provably incorrect, at worst it's simply bad code style. A linter tool is never going to fault you for it, or if it does, the linter tool is wrong.

### write your own

Advantages:

- There's no chance that users of your library bring faulty assumptions (that IAE means: Argument is illegal regardless of state); that makes it less confusing.
- If code intends to call your method and write a catch clause specifically for the condition of removing more than is there, then this is definitely the nicest answer. This:

```java
try {
  product.decreaseQuantity(5);
} catch (QuantityInsufficientException e) {
  ui.showOrderingError("Regretfully we don't have this item in stock at the quantity you want");
}
```

Is slightly more readable than `catch (IllegalArgumentException)`, and more importantly, is more reliable: IAE is such an oft-used exception that you're going to one day edit the `decreaseQuantity` method and introduce a code path that throws IAE for some other reason and now you have a very hard to find bug.

### Conclusion

I'd be writing your own. Yes, it's a bit of a drag to have to write the source file, but you can let your IDE (or [Project Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/StandardException) for maximum boilerplate busting) generate the entire file and you probably never have to look at `InsufficientQuantityException.java` ever again.

Answer (score 0):

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException` is the right answer in this case.

This example is equivalent to the following one from *Effective Java - Third Edition* (page 301):

> Consider the case of
> an object representing a deck of cards, and suppose there were a method to deal a
> hand from the deck that took as an argument the size of the hand. If the caller
> passed a value larger than the number of cards remaining in the deck, it could be
> construed as an IllegalArgumentException (the handSize parameter value is too
> high) or an IllegalStateException (the deck contains too few cards). **Under
> these circumstances, the rule is to throw IllegalStateException if no argument
> values would have worked, otherwise throw IllegalArgumentException.**

The`IllegalStateException` is not correct because the state of the object does not prevent to invoke `decreaseQuantity`: you can invoke it, **just use an appropriate input value**.

Comment: The problem is, IAE is not an appropriate exception to throw if you intend for callers to be capable of detecting this specific condition and reacting to it. Effective Java's chapter on this is regrettably substandard compared to the stellar quality of the rest of that book, but the question has not indicated they expect callers to want to respond to the specific condition. Still, given that this need (to allow callers to respond specifically to insufficient quantity) seems plausible to me, I find the wording "is the right answer in this case" inappropriate.

Comment: @rzwitserloot Indeed, you are right. I have projected into this answer my knowledge of the situation around the question I asked. This answer should be rephrased as "given my situation, IllegalArgumentException is the most suitable answer." and update the post with more information about why I prefer this over the custom exception. Your answer is better because it evaluates the possible options and helps you think which one best suits your specific situation. For these reasons I accept yours.